# How can I disable the cache for a specific page or have the cache ignore query params?

Tags: 8, caching

I need to disable the cache for a specific page, or get the cache to ignore query params. I have tried this, but it does not disable the cache for me https://www.drupal.org/project/page_cache_query_ignore

After trying multiple ways to disable the cache for a specific page or even the whole site I have nothing that works.

I have tried all of these in `settings.php`

```
$settings['cache']['default'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['page'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['entity'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

There is also talk of using `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();` but I am unsure where to place this to disable the cache for a regular page.

This is for the search page, that uses query params for the search query. Drupal 8 is caching the page so each visit to the search after the first search always shows the results for the first search.

The header for Drupal dynamic cache is always a HIT

`X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache:    HIT`

Comment: When you say you want cache to ignore query params, do you mean that you want the page to be cached separately for each possible query param? What kind of page is it? Does the whole page depend on the query parameters? or just a piece of content on the page, e.g. the main content area? It sounds like you need to add a `url.query_args` [cache context](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-contexts#core-contexts) somewhere, but will need more info to tell you where.

Comment: It is the search page if that helps, and there is another page that needs to ignore query params too, this is just a regular page as far as I know. Caching not at all or individually is fine. This is not a module, it just a page with a search on it and another page.

Comment: Is the site behind Varnish or similar?

Comment: Yes, but the issue is on every environment, even local with no caching of that sort

Comment: Definitely sounds like you’ve got something non-standard configured. If manually setting the cache backends to null in settings.php doesn’t stop the caches being used, and you’re positive there’s no external reverse proxy responsible, you probably have some dodgy code in there somewhere. What powers the search page? Search API or core?

Comment: I believe Search API

Comment: And the cache for the view is properly configured?

Comment: Well, it works, but the cache is always on, even the homepage, see @jbarrio answer and my response. Nothing I do affects the cache. I did not set up the search. At present, it would be nice to just have the cache off anywhere at all.

Comment: Doing it in settings.php will affect all pages. The kill switch code you can place it inside of `theme_name_preprocess_page(&$vars){` in your theme_name.theme file. And you'll need to add a conditional that checks the route or the path of the page.

Comment: But anyhow, your issue is something else as I never had to use kill switch for the search page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trying and retrying I settled on the following solution

```
function mythemename_preprocess_page(&$variables)
{
  if(isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $params = \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\parse_query($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    if(isset($params['keys']) && strlen($params['keys']) > 0 && preg_match('#^/search#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
      \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this stops the cache from working if the request is on the search page and there is a query parameter present named `keys`

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that if you haven't been able to completely turn off cache then something is still preventing you from fully loading 'fresh' pages on every request, which may mean there's still some parameter deep down that you might consider reconfiguring. I'd suggest to follow this guide to [Disable Drupal 8 caching during development](https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914) on your local environment before going mad.

Comment: I have followed that and still get `X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache HIT` after visiting a page and then refreshing

Comment: If you’ve disabled Drupal’s cache, but everything is still cached, it means you’re either connected to a proxy in front of Drupal, not Drupal, or you have some code in the site causing the problem. If you’re convinced the reverse proxy isn’t it, you should probably contact whoever set up the search, or prepare for a debugging session

Comment: It's not related to the search as it happens on all pages. *Should* what I have done in my original post disable the cache?

Comment: Assuming you have a development.services.yml defining the null cache backend, and that’s also included via settings.pho, then yes

Comment: You can of course prove it by truncating all the tables in the database beginning `cache_`. If that fixes it, the problem is probably in code, otherwise it’s probably an external cache layer

Comment: Yes that fixes it, truncating all `cache_*` tables makes a new version of the page show

Comment: It looks like maybe you had a cached site, then applied the non cache settings but maybe, just maybe, you forgot to execute 'drush cr' or clear cache from the UI so all cache_* tables still had data on them.